# Drupal 6 securing files in custom module folder

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-6

I wrote a custom module, which logs errors to an external text file. The files are kept in

```
/sites/all/modules/custom/my_module/logging/
```

The problem is, if the user know the name of the file, they can go directly to it. For example, if they go to:

```
http://localhost/MySite/web/sites/all/modules/custom/my_module/logging/
```

The will get a forbidden error. But, if they know the name of the document and go to:

```
http://localhost/MySite/web/sites/all/modules/custom/my_module/logging/myFile.txt
```

the full file is rendered to the browser. Is there a way to prevent this? Ideally, I would like to show the files to certain users but at the very least prevent it all together.

thanks jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simple method...

Put a `.htaccess` file in the logging folder and inside that put

```
deny from all
```

It looks like you have somewhere `options -indexes`, this will prevent a client viewing a folder that does not have an index file